# After update do spring-boot 2.3.0 webflux webclient ignores added jackson2JsonDecoder

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

After I've updated to spring-boot 2.3.0 (so my webflux WebClient is now from version 5.2.6) custom ObjectMapper is completely ignored. My configuration looks as follows

```
public static WebClient buildWebClient(WebClient.Builder builder) {
    return builder
            .defaultHeader(ACCEPT, APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_ENCODING, "identity")
            .exchangeStrategies(ExchangeStrategies
                    .builder()
                    .codecs(codecConfigurer -> {
                        codecConfigurer.defaultCodecs().jackson2JsonDecoder(buildJsonDeserializer());
                    })
                    .build())
            .build();
} 

public static Jackson2JsonDecoder buildJsonDeserializer() {
    ObjectMapper customObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule();
    simpleModule.addDeserializer(Map.class, new JsonDeserializer<Map<String, String>>() {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt)
                throws IOException {
            ...
        }
    });
    customObjectMapper.registerModule(simpleModule);
    return new Jackson2JsonDecoder(customObjectMapper, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
}
```

There is bug in new version or it's just something that have changed and I don't know how to set it now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
WebClient.builder()
        .defaultHeader(ACCEPT, APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_ENCODING, "identity")
        .codecs(configurer -> {
          configurer.customCodecs().registerWithDefaultConfig(buildJsonDeserializer());
        })
        .build();
```

Here is the [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-codecs-custom) to the official doc.